# Implement a Regression/Classification Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, logistic-regression

#### Problem Context

I am trying to learn Neural Networks in Python, & I've developed an implementation of a Logistic Regression based NN.

Here is the code -

```
import numpy as np

# Input array
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

# Output
y = np.array([[1], [1], [0]])


# Sigmoid Function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


# Derivative of Sigmoid Function
def ddx_sigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)


#####   Initialization - BEGIN  #####


# Setting training iterations
iterations_max = 500000

# Learning Rate
alpha = 0.5

# Number of Neruons in Input Layer = Number of Features in the data set
inputlayer_neurons = X.shape[1]

# Number of Neurons in the Hidden Layer
hiddenlayer_neurons = 3  # number of hidden layers neurons

# Number of Neurons at the Output Layer
output_neurons = 1  # number of neurons at output layer

# weight and bias initialization
wh = np.random.uniform(size=(inputlayer_neurons, hiddenlayer_neurons))
bh = np.random.uniform(size=(1, hiddenlayer_neurons))
wout = np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenlayer_neurons, output_neurons))
bout = np.random.uniform(size=(1, output_neurons))

#####   Initialization - END  #####

# Printing of shapes

print "\nShape X: ", X.shape, "\nShape Y: ", y.shape
print "\nShape WH: ", wh.shape, "\nShape BH: ", bh.shape, "\nShape Wout: ", wout.shape, "\nShape Bout: ", bout.shape

# Printing of Values
print "\nwh:\n", wh, "\n\nbh: ", bh, "\n\nwout:\n", wout, "\n\nbout: ", bout

#####   TRAINING - BEGIN  #####
for i in range(iterations_max):
    #####   Forward Propagation - BEGIN   #####

    # Input to Hidden Layer = (Dot Product of Input Layer and Weights) + Bias
    hidden_layer_input = (np.dot(X, wh)) + bh

    # Activation of input to Hidden Layer by using Sigmoid Function
    hiddenlayer_activations = sigmoid(hidden_layer_input)

    # Input to Output Layer = (Dot Product of Hidden Layer Activations and Weights) + Bias
    output_layer_input = np.dot(hiddenlayer_activations, wout) + bout

    # Activation of input to Output Layer by using Sigmoid Function
    output = sigmoid(output_layer_input)

    #####   Forward Propagation - END #####

    #####   Backward Propagation - BEGIN   #####

    E = y - output

    slope_output_layer = ddx_sigmoid(output)
    slope_hidden_layer = ddx_sigmoid(hiddenlayer_activations)

    d_output = E * slope_output_layer

    Error_at_hidden_layer = d_output.dot(wout.T)
    d_hiddenlayer = Error_at_hidden_layer * slope_hidden_layer

    wout += hiddenlayer_activations.T.dot(d_output) * alpha
    bout += np.sum(d_output, axis=0, keepdims=True) * alpha

    wh += X.T.dot(d_hiddenlayer) * alpha
    bh += np.sum(d_hiddenlayer, axis=0, keepdims=True) * alpha

    #####   Backward Propagation - END   #####
#####   TRAINING - END  #####

print "\nOutput is:\n", output
```

This code is working perfectly in the cases where the output is binary (0,1). I guess, this is because of the sigmoid function I am using.

#### Problem

Now, I want to scale this code so that it can handle linear regression as well.

As we know, the `scikit` library has some preloaded datasets which can be used for classification and regression.

I want my NN to train and test the `diabetes` dataset.

With this in mind, I have modified my code as follows -

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

# Sigmoid Function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


# Derivative of Sigmoid Function
def ddx_sigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

# Load Data
def load_data():
    diabetes_data = datasets.load_diabetes()
    return diabetes_data

input_data = load_data()

X = input_data.data

# Reshape Output
y = input_data.target
y = y.reshape(len(y), 1)

iterations_max = 1000

# Learning Rate
alpha = 0.5

# Number of Neruons in Input Layer = Number of Features in the data set
inputlayer_neurons = X.shape[1]

# Number of Neurons in the Hidden Layer
hiddenlayer_neurons = 5  # number of hidden layers neurons

# Number of Neurons at the Output Layer
output_neurons = 3  # number of neurons at output layer

# weight and bias initialization
wh = np.random.uniform(size=(inputlayer_neurons, hiddenlayer_neurons))
bh = np.random.uniform(size=(1, hiddenlayer_neurons))
wout = np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenlayer_neurons, output_neurons))
bout = np.random.uniform(size=(1, output_neurons))


#####   TRAINING - BEGIN  #####
for i in range(iterations_max):
    #####   Forward Propagation - BEGIN   #####

    # Input to Hidden Layer = (Dot Product of Input Layer and Weights) + Bias
    hidden_layer_input = (np.dot(X, wh)) + bh

    # Activation of input to Hidden Layer by using Sigmoid Function
    hiddenlayer_activations = sigmoid(hidden_layer_input)

    # Input to Output Layer = (Dot Product of Hidden Layer Activations and Weights) + Bias
    output_layer_input = np.dot(hiddenlayer_activations, wout) + bout

    # Activation of input to Output Layer by using Sigmoid Function
    output = sigmoid(output_layer_input)

    #####   Forward Propagation - END #####

    #####   Backward Propagation - BEGIN   #####

    E = y - output

    slope_output_layer = ddx_sigmoid(output)
    slope_hidden_layer = ddx_sigmoid(hiddenlayer_activations)

    d_output = E * slope_output_layer

    Error_at_hidden_layer = d_output.dot(wout.T)
    d_hiddenlayer = Error_at_hidden_layer * slope_hidden_layer

    wout += hiddenlayer_activations.T.dot(d_output) * alpha
    bout += np.sum(d_output, axis=0, keepdims=True) * alpha

    wh += X.T.dot(d_hiddenlayer) * alpha
    bh += np.sum(d_hiddenlayer, axis=0, keepdims=True) * alpha

    #####   Backward Propagation - END   #####
#####   TRAINING - END  #####

print "\nOutput is:\n", output
```

The output of this code is -

```
Output is:
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

Obviously, I am goofing up somewhere in the basics.

Is this because I am using the sigmoid function for the hidden as well as the output layer?

What kind of functions shall I use so that I get a valid output, which can be used to train my NN efficiently?

#### Efforts so far

I have tried to use the TANH function, the SOFTPLUS function as activation to both the layers, without any success.

Can someone out here please help?

I tried Googling this but the explanations there are very complex.

HELP !

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove sigmoid function on your output.

As for linear regression, output range may be large, while output of sigmoid or tanh function is [0, 1] or [-1, 1], which makes minimize of error function not possible.

======= UPDATE ======

I try to accomplish it in tensorflow, the core part for it:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([features, FLAGS.hidden_unit], stddev=0.35))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([FLAGS.hidden_unit]))

# right way
y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(x, w) + b, 1)

# wrong way: as sigmoid output in [-1, 1]
# y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, w) + b)

mse_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y - y_, 2) / 2
```

Comment: Agreed. So can I use the linear or SOFTMAX function for the output, and the sigmoid function for the input?

Additionally, is there a way so that I can train this model on the diabetes dataset?

Comment: yes, you should not use sigmoid function as its range [-1, 1].  Of course you could train model on diabetes dataset

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the update, although I am looking to implement this without any custom library, apart from NumPy and MatPlotLib ! 

"As for linear regression, output range may be large, while output of sigmoid or tanh function is [0, 1] or [-1, 1], which makes minimize of error function not possible." - Can you please elaborate on this?

What I am looking for here is, after the training is complete, I will enter random values in the feeatures as a test, and my model should predict the output correctly.

Comment: For example, the true y of one instance is 100, while the predict y of sigmoid is between [-1, 1], so the maxium of predict value is 1, while the error of true and predict y couldn't be minimize with limitation of predict value.   It has nothing to do with train or test, because test also use sigmoid as output, which also limits range of output